# How do I strip all query string besides one directory from URL?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to force rewrite all url using queries `/?campaign=whatever` etc.

I wrote something like this (I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?]*)\? 
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

How can I tell apache not to rewrite only directory `/admin/` ?

Also, if anyone knows if it's possible to mess up some other services using this technique? I don't need analytics campaigns etc, people just link with their own stupid tracking urls to my blog and it bypasses the cache but I can't change the cache system currently.

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/admin/
http://www.example.com/admin/pages.php?var=blabla

(anything after or /admin/) - ignore
```

Else - clean the query strings.

Comment: Could you write an example what should be rewritten and what should not?

Comment: I added the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin(?:/.*)?$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

1. Check if query string contains something.
2. Check the `request URI` if it does not start with `/admin/`.
3. If all conditions are met, redirect URL - remove query string.

Comment: But when or how do I use regex to to check for query strings..  ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?]*)\? do I need some kind of AND operator?

Comment: @BadrHari I see. You don't want to redirect URL if it doesn't contain query string, do you?

Comment: Not really, I want to remove all query strings but only not in /admin/ path or it's subpaths... www.example.com/blog-post?campaign_source=test -> redirect to www.example.com/blog-post . www.example.com/admin?var=2, www.example.com/admin/pages/var=3&var2=4 - never redirect.

Comment: @BadrHari I updated my answer, it should do what you want now.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I need to test it. I was looking but didn't find .+ operator... is using QUERY_STRING better than my regex?

Comment: @BadrHari I think it is. Your regex seems to me a bit complicated.